# Tensoring subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $E\subset X$, be a subspace and let $\hat{\otimes}$ denote the projective tensor product. Denote $L_1 = L_1 [0,1]$. Does $E\hat{\otimes} L_1$ embed into $X \hat{\otimes} L_1$?

This is easy to see if you replace $L_1$ by $\ell_1$, though I cannot see it in this generality. Does the result remain valid if we replace $L_1$ by any $L_1(\mu)$-space with $\mu$ possibly infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. This is Theorem 2.20 in Ryan's ["Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces"](http://books.google.nl/books?id=7xRlVTVSNpQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=tensor%20products%20ryan&ei=XYrtUKKgCZKqzQTU7ICADQ&cd=1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tensor%20products%20ryan&f=false). Concluding this is not as straightforward as for $\ell_1$, since it relies on recognizing a special structure on the finite dimensional subspaces of $L_1$ (details are in Section 2.4 of Ryan's book).

Comment: It sounds as if you are suggesting a detour via $\mathfrak{L}_1$-spaces. This is not necessary here. Just identify $L^1(\mu) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}} E$ with the space $L^1(\mu,E)$ of Bochner integrable functions: in both spaces the space of (integrable) simple functions is dense and the map from the algebraic tensor product to $L^1(\mu,E)$ is isometric, hence it extends to an isometric isomorphism (all this is nothing but writing out the definitions). That tensoring with $L^1(\mu)$ respects subspaces isometrically is then a straightforward verification.

Comment: @J.Lund I checked in Google books. In Ryan my remark is discussed in [example 2.19](http://books.google.com/books?id=7xRlVTVSNpQC&pg=PA29) and the remarks following it on page 30.

Comment: @Martin. Good point, thanks. One tends to miss important remarks when flitting through too quickly. :P